# Python Django Unittests: How to tear down fixtures

Tags: python, django

I need to write some tests for my Django-App. For that I am using fixtures which I load like that:

```
    from django.test import TestCase    

    class PermissionTest(TestCase):
        fixtures = ['test_groups.json','test_users.json']

        def setUp(self):       
        ... some other stuff
```

Now I am wondering what to write in my tearDown-Method to delete the groups and users generated from my fixtures. Or are they deleted automatically?

```
        def tearDown(self):
            ... what has to go here?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deletion of the loaded fixtures will be taken care of by django's testing framework before running each test. So you don't need to handle this.

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#fixture-loading):

> Here’s specifically what will happen:
>
> At the start of each test case, before setUp() is run, Django will flush the database, returning the database to the state it was in directly after migrate was called.
>
> Then, all the named fixtures are installed. In this example, Django will install any JSON fixture named mammals, followed by any fixture named birds. See the loaddata documentation for more details on defining and installing fixtures.
>
> This flush/load procedure is repeated for each test in the test case, so you can be certain that the outcome of a test will not be affected by another test, or by the order of test execution.

Comment: Ah, ok! Thanks. Should have found this myself :-)

Comment: This is not technically the correct answer. If multiple tests are run that touch common tables, sometimes not all of the records are torn down. There are times I've had to use `TransactionTestCase` to properly clean up after a test.

Comment: This does not seem to hold true for multiple apps in one single project. Is there a way I can manually clear the table after the tests end?